# Empty value displayed for div background color

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to listen to click events on div elements. 
HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="1" class="square"></div>
    <div id="2" class="square"></div>
    <div id="3" class="square"></div>
    <div id="4" class="square"></div>
    <div id="5" class="square"></div>
    <div id="6" class="square"></div>
    <div id="7" class="square"></div>
    <div id="8" class="square"></div>
    <div id="9" class="square"></div>
    <div id="10" class="square"></div>
    <div id="11" class="square"></div>
    <div id="12" class="square"></div>
    <div id="13" class="square"></div>
    <div id="14" class="square"></div>
    <div id="15" class="square"></div>
    <div id="16" class="square"></div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) { 
if (e.target && e.target.matches("div"))
{
    console.log("Square element clicked!");

    SquareBackground=this.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(SquareBackground);
    SquareId=this.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(SquareId);
}
});
```

I have created an array for setting the background color of the div elements and the code works properly in the browser. When I click on any square divs, I am getting the "Square Element clicked" message. However, when I try to print the background color of the clicked div, I am getting an empty value in the console. Also, for the second output, I am getting "container" instead of the id of the clicked div. Please help.

EDIT:
This function is used to set the background color for the squares. The array combinedColors[] contains randomly generated RGB values eg. rgb(255,0,9).

```
function changeSquareColor()
{
    for(i=0;i<squares.length;i++)
    {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor=combinedColors[i];
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
    .square{
        width: 20%;
        background: blue;
        float:left;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
        margin: 1.66%;
    }

body{
    background-color: black;
}

#container{

    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 600px;
};
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have any CSS or styles to set a background colour[sic]

Comment: Are you using any external file related to CSS? please inform about that

Comment: ohh so you are setting the background color with javascript, when?

Comment: @Phiter: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. The array has randomly generated RGB values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`HTMLElement.style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) will get only inline styles (`<div style="color: blue;">`).

The `backgroundColor` in your element comes from its class (I guess), not an inline style.

To get the currently applied/computed style, you have to use [**`window.getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('blueDiv');
var pre = document.getElementById('style');
pre.innerHTML = 'Its background color is: ' + window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

```css
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="blueDiv" class="blue">
  I'm blue da bu dee da bu die
</div>

<pre id="style"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for some reason if you set the background color in a css class it won't see it but inline it retrieves it fine. Also the this code wasn't returning and id or color but if you use the target div you can get its properties.

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("div")) {
    console.log("Square element clicked!");

    SquareBackground = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(SquareBackground);
    SquareId = e.target.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(SquareId);
  }
});
```

```css
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" style=
" background-color:red;" class="square"></div>
  <div id="2"  style=
" background-color:blue;" class="square"></div>
  <div id="3" class="square"></div>
  <div id="4" class="square"></div>
  <div id="5" class="square"></div>
  <div id="6" class="square"></div>
  <div id="7" class="square"></div>
  <div id="8" class="square"></div>
  <div id="9" class="square"></div>
  <div id="10" class="square"></div>
  <div id="11" class="square"></div>
  <div id="12" class="square"></div>
  <div id="13" class="square"></div>
  <div id="14" class="square"></div>
  <div id="15" class="square"></div>
  <div id="16" class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my answer as for why it brings the style only if it's inline.